# Cannot connect to Chase Bank

Tags: plaid

I try to use Plaid to connect Chase Bank on Development environment, but it show issue: "You may need to update your app in order to connect to Chase" on my native app use SDK (Website still link success)

I had OAuth for development environment, but it still not work.

Please help me in this case
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You need to have Production access approved and be specifically OAuth enabled for Chase. Check the status for Chase at https://dashboard.plaid.com/team/oauth-institutions to see your status and if there are any steps you need to take.